# Creating a check constraint for multiple specific inputs

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I assumed it would be fine to execute SQL ommand something like this

Installation' OR 'Software Repair'

This didn't work so well so I tried

This didn't go so great either, I got a missing expression for Data Recovery

This gave me a cannot validate SYS.CH_SERVICETYPE -check constraint violated

Does this mean this constraint is already in place? If not

How can I enforce a Check Constraint for a table to require only specific values?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the IN keyword.

```
ServiceType in ('Training', 'Data_Recovery', 'Consultation', 'Software  Installation', 'Software Repair')
```

Comment: Yeah I get cannot validate (SYS.CK_SERVICETYPE) - check constraint violated I guess this means that its already enforced ? Or there is like another constraint that is not allowing this to only = these values

Comment: That means, ServiceType column already has values other then what you have mentioned in the Constraint. Do a SELECT DISTINCT on ServiceType column to see what values it has.

Comment: Nah found it, had a _ in data type and a double space between Software and installation, it was case sensitive the current CK Thanks for the In statement, really helped out cheers!